# Activity shall not start before mHomeReady - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I just opened my android studio this morning and i tried to compile the app i was working on and bam the Error:

```
Error while executing: am start -n "org.cocetonko.app.cocetonko/org.cocetonko.app.cocetonko.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error: Activity shall not start before mHomeReady: org.cocetonko.app.cocetonko/org.cocetonko.app.cocetonko.MainActivity

Error while Launching activity
```

MainActivity code

```
package org.cocetonko.app.cocetonko;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Note this happen to every project even the older ones that were working before and the new project that I just created. Also, am running them on physical device Androidone version 8.1.0.

I even created a new project, trying to run it, the same error occurred. My android studio version is 3.2.1

Guys! please, I don't know what is wrong, I need help.

Comment: can u attach Main activity code for this ?

Comment: I tried looking for this error message or variable name "mHomeReady" in the Android open source code, but it's no where to be found. Try to reboot your phone or create a new emulator, maybe it's a proprietary piece of code that is the reason for this. Also, some more code would be great to help you out.

Comment: The code is just a simple basic structure for every new project

Comment: `package org.cocetonko.app.cocetonko;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}`

Note this happen to every project even the older ones that were working before and the new project that I just created. Also, am running them on physical device Androidone version 8.1.0.